# Django show only one element

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have product with image but when i try show image only this product django show me all image product how i can fix it ? I try wite slice don't work beacuse if i do |slice:"0:1" show me image but not image this product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='product')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    promo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    news = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SECTION_CHOICES, default=None)
    detailimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/detail/%Y/%m/%d',
                                    blank=True)
    detailimagetwo = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/detail/%Y/%m/%d',
                                    blank=True)
 class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.name

 @property
 def image_url(self):
    if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
        return self.image.url

 @property
 def detail_url(self):
    if self.detailimage and hasattr(self.detailimage, 'url'):
        return self.detailimage.url

 @property
 def detailtwo_url(self):
    if self.detailimagetwo and hasattr(self.detailimagetwo, 'url'):
        return self.detailimagetwo.url

 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                   args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

My views.py

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)
    products = Product.objects.all()

    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product,
                   'products': products})
```

and my detail.html

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}{{ product.name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for p in products %}
    <img src="{{p.detail_url}}" class="img-responsive">
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

if u want somethink more comment and i will how fast i can add it .

Comment: You want to show only one product? Because you are looping all products. Did you copy this code from somewhere else?

Comment: No i create it. And i m done. Mby is easy but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Well its hard to understand your english and what is your problem, What is your native language? Maybe there is version of stackoverflow in it

Answer (score 0):

change your view

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)

    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product})
```

and in template change

```
{% for p in products %}
```

to

```
{% for p in product %}
```

you can solve the problem by removing one 's' in template but i suggest change the view function as mentioned

in case your using Pillow not just the address of image as string change this

```
{{p.detail_url}}
```

to

```
{{p.fieldname.url}}
```